# Java - Connect to MySQL without specifying username and password inside the code

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, jdbc

I'm looking for a way to open a JDBC connection without specifying my database login and password in plain text, as the application will be distributed and any Java decompiler would reveal them, allowing the users to access the database easily.

Is there any way to encrypt them, or store them somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want to let Android application talk to your database directly? Don't do that. It's a major security flaw. No matter how you encrypt your credential, you have to reveal your plain text somewhere during the execution of the program, and anyone with a debugger can see that. The correct way is to have use an API on your web service and call that API from client. All database transaction should happen in a trusted intranet.

Comment: In connection to this I recommend using JSON messages sent through an encrypted (TLS/SSL) connection to a webserver, which then handles the request and sends back a response to the mobile device ("Success!", "John Johnson", "42", etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to do this? Generally the business side of your application would have this info and connect to MySQL. There, a user does not have access to any code. Then you create an endpoint that actually is accessible to the public. There you can worry about passing username and password stuff to the business logic, which again, actually has direct access to your database.

Basically, do not open a jdbc connection anywhere but your server side. Its a security measure.